# How to use "which" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I bought two new movie tickets from eBay, which are for my son's birthday.

I bought two new movie tickets from eBay, which is a nice website for buying and selling personal things.

In the first sentence, "which" represents "two movie tickets"
In the second one, "which" represents "eBay websites"

Which "which" is correct usage?

Comment: They are both correct, and they mean different things.

Comment: @buzz why do you think one is incorrect?

Comment: I assume "which" should normally represent the noun before preposition.

Comment: It's easier for the reader, if not absolutely required, to put the relative clause as close as possible to the noun it attaches to. 'I bought two new movie tickets, which are for my son's birthday, from eBay.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both are grammatically correct because they (both which) refer to two different subjects.

But maybe the first one still sounds ambiguous so you can change it into :

"I bought two new movie tickets which are for my son's birthday from e-Bay".

Cmiiw.